# Создание элементов в java Script

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как более продуктивно создавать громоздкие элементы в JS, например всплывающее окно с инпутами - делать это через document.createElement или с помощью innerHtml = '............'???

Comment: Конечно можно создавать элементы через js, но лучше создать необходимый блок/элемент используя html, а управлять поведением через javascript

Comment: то есть вы имеете ввиду, создать например элемент на html странице и скрыть его а потом js показывать и заполнять поля например из бд? верно?

Comment: да, все правильно ты понял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И так про создание элементов:

1) создавать элементы при помощи  **html**,  скрывать их, затем при необходимости отображать.

**преимущества** - легкая реализация не зависимо от сложности формы.

**недостатки** - при повторном применении  - дублирование кода.

2) создавать элементы при помощи **createElement**, вставлять их в элементы при необходимости

**преимущества** -удобно добавлять, динамически в любое нужное место. возможность повторного использования

**недостатки** - создание сложных элементов громоздкое.

3) размещать при помощи **innerHTML** - вполне реализуемо (можно использовать шаблонные строки '`<input type='text' value='${valiable}'/>`' ). но страдает производительность. как альтернатива - `element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, textHTML)` - более производительный метод ( без дополнительно сериализации.)

**преимущества** - простота использования, можно переиспользовать

**недостатки** - при вставке простого текста  не рекоммендуют использовать из соображений безопасности

4) **React/Vue** - работа с шаблонами на более высоком уровне(абстрагируются от всех  вышеперечисленных методов хотя под капотом их и используют), дают много возможностей  для создания шаблонов, переиспользования кода

**преимущества** - вышесказанное +  большое количество готовых решений, возможность тестирования уже на более высоком уровне, активное использование на большинстве современных проектов

**недостатки** - тянут с собой много лишнего.  думаю что не совсем подойдут для  совсем уж простых страниц/сайтов. у новичков могут вызывать много вопросов  в понимании происходящего. требуют знания  и понимания  js + основ функционального программирования

все это достаточно в общем написано, но думаю что общую идею донес.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, то что нужно. больше понимания как реализовать задачи

Comment: React и Vue используют ООП прадигму. Причём тут функциональное программирование?

Comment: при том  что просто откройте , начните читать и первые же понятия в учебнике по реакт -HOK функции, чистые функции, функции высшего порядка, иммутабельность, сайд эфекты - это  уж точно в ООП не входило.

Comment: Очень странно. Похоже что это приколы автора учебника. На оффсайте в туториале ни о чём подобном не говорится.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться HTML5 [элементом `<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) и его API.

```js
// Получаем шаблон. Переменная t будет содержать
// найденный элемент <template> и являться объектом
// класса HTMLElement.
var t = document.querySelector('#productrow');


// Получаем тело таблицы (место, куда будем вставлять новые строки)
var tb = document.querySelector("tbody");

// Из свойства content объекта t получаем представление того, что
// будем вставлять в таблицу в виде DocumentFragment
var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);

// Теперь получаем все ячейки вставляемой строки и наполняем их контентом
var td = clone.querySelectorAll("td");
td[0].textContent = "1235646565";
td[1].textContent = "Stuff";

// В тело таблицы вставляем "клона", то есть уже наполненный шаблон
tb.appendChild(clone);

// Операцию можно повторять сколько угодно раз
var clone2 = document.importNode(t.content, true);
td = clone2.querySelectorAll("td");
td[0].textContent = "0384928528";
td[1].textContent = "Acme Kidney Beans 2";

tb.appendChild(clone2);
```

```html
<table id="producttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>UPC_Code</td>
      <td>Product_Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- existing data could optionally be included here -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<template id="productrow">
  <tr>
    <td class="record"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Пример выше является адаптированным примером с MDN (ссылка вверху). Аналогично можно составить шаблон (template) для всплывающего окна и открывать (показывать) это окно только при каких-нибудь событиях. Например, при нажатии на кнопку.

Преимущество такого подхода, очевидно, заключается в том, что с представлением вы работаете непосредственно в HTML и его не приходится тянуть в логику (а разделение - это хорошо), а вот уже за наполнение шаблона динамическим контентом отвечает JS (конечно, статические данные разумным будет прямо в шаблоне и прописывать). Плюс, очевидно, переиспользование кода. Создали шаблон для всплывающего окна один раз, а вставляете его на страницу как хотите и когда хотите сколько угодно раз.